# Wordpress on Google App Engine (Pricing)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I like Google App Engine's pricing, and plans, and would like to know if hosting wordpress website is feasible or not. I am planning to make a wordpress website, and would like to host it on wordpress if the pricing is cheap.

My website will not have many users , around 100-200 users a day (maximum). So, while no requests are being processed, will I be getting charged for the CloudSQL instance(or will it shut down ?).

I would like someone to give me a sense of the pricing. I will be getting 100-200 visitors per day, and the pages are around 500-700 kbs big(10-20 pages).

Can somebody give real world example pricing for wordpress ? (i do NOT want links to the pricing calculator, i have already gone through that)

Comment: question is about pricing not programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been using App Engine for running a very small WordPress website just in order to learn more about the technology and paid

- $04.89 for 5872.695 App Engine **Front-End-Instance** minutes
- $11.16 for 31 days of **Cloud SQL D0**
- $00.06 for 63172 **Cloud Storage Class B** Requests

for the month of November and December which amounts to $8.05 per month. So it's almost the same as paying for shared hosting I'd say. It looks like the Cloud SQL instance does not shut down.

[image: Google Analytics stats]

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of the [free trial](https://console.developers.google.com/billing/freetrial?hl=en&_ga=1.230625950.369800063.1390537036), which should give you a good indication of your costs

From your description you would not incur any cost on the app engine side (it would run inside the free quotas), your only cost would be Cloud SQL.

Comment: i have started using the free trial, but I am not able to get my daily costs( the billing page is blank) it shows I have $299.84 left. but HOW, and WHY, I cant find